# requireActivity().contentResolver.query(…) returning 0 elements for API 30

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am following the big nerd ranch guide book for android programming, and it turns out is a bit out of date..
I am trying to get a contact name from the contact list and store it in the database; the problem is, when I try to run the code on the emulator and i choose API level 30, it doesn’t save the contact to the database, while if I try to run the project on a lower API, it works just fine.
Here is the code

```
pickContactCallback = ActivityResultCallback<Uri?> { contactUri: Uri?->
        val queryFields = arrayOf(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)
        val cursor = contactUri?.let { contactUri ->
            Log.d(TAG, "check if contact exists: ${contactUri.toString()}")
            requireActivity().contentResolver.query(
                contactUri,
                queryFields,
                null,
                null,
                null
            )
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "n. of contacts: ${cursor!!.count.toString()}") // this is 0 with API 30, 2 with API 29
        cursor?.use {
            if (it.count == 0){
                return@ActivityResultCallback
            }

            it.moveToFirst()
            val suspect = it.getString(0)
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() called - $suspect")
            crime.suspect = suspect
            crimeDetailViewModel.saveCrime(crime)
            suspectButton.text = suspect
        }
    }
```

I already added permission in the manifest file like so

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
```

What am I missing? does anyone knows what I’m doing wrong?
Thanks so much, I've been working on this all day, and I can't find any solution.

Comment: I removed the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> line, cleaned the project, wiped the emulator and restarted and everything seems to work now. However, I do not understand why, shouldn't that line help?